# integrate useMemo with debounce

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, frontend, lodash

I have a website has a searchBar section and when a user type in input element a http call trigger to looking for a name that inserted,
now my question here: If I want to reducing the time and http request numbers,
it is better I use a debounce to prevent from many http calls and if I want to use useMemo hook as well , how can I approach? and totally in this situation what is the best approach.
this is my code :

```
function SearchBar() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
 


  const debouncedFunc = useMemo(
    () => _.debounce((userInput) => getData(userInput), 1000),
    []
  );
 

  async function getData(query: string) {
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}&query=${query}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const movies = await res.json();
    setData(movies.results);
  }

  const handleInput = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const userInput = e.target.value;
    };

 
     
}
```

Comment: `getData` is a dependency of the memo